# Does the "ID not found in layout" error in Dash impact the efficiency of the application?

Tags: python, performance, plotly-dash

I am creating a Dash application, and I have some elements that do not exist initially. They are created based on user-specific actions. Due to this, I am encountering numerous "ID not found" errors, and I'm concerned about the impact on the performance of my application, especially since I have 54 of these errors.

[image]